# Android layout with vertical adjustment between 2 inner containers

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to know what kind of layout is this? top image part (A) is pinch zoom (so I guess ImageView with something like photoView implemented), bottom part (C) is vertical scroll (so this would be RecyclerView), but middle part (B) dragger can be dragged up and down, thus enlarging the portion of one container (A or C)  / reducing the portion of another, depending where is dragged.

[image]

Comment: maybe a custom bottom sheet with recycler view inside.